# Is $\phi(t) = \frac{1}{2}[\cos(t) + \cos(t\pi)] $ absolutely continuous?

Tags: probability, distributions, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

X is a real-valued random variable with characteristic function:

$\hspace{20mm}$$\phi(t) = \frac{1}{2}[\cos(t) + \cos(t\pi)]$, $\hspace{10mm}-\infty<t<\infty$.

1. Is the distribution of X completely continuous?
2. Is there an $r$ such that $E(X^r)$ does not exist or is infinite?

   1. The distribution is not absolutely continuous as the limit of $\sin(x)$ as $x$ approaches infinity does not exist.
   2. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$ (up to some convention-dependent constants),

$$
\delta_x \stackrel{\mathcal{F}}{\mapsto} e^{itx}.
$$

So

$$
\frac{1}{2} (\delta_1 + \delta_{-1}) \stackrel{\mathcal{F}}{\mapsto} \cos t,
$$

and

$$
\frac{1}{2} (\delta_{\pi} + \delta_{-\pi}) \stackrel{\mathcal{F}}{\mapsto} \cos \pi t,
$$

So your $X$ induces the uniform measure supported on $\{1, -1, \pi, -\pi\}$.